# CUDA FFT does not return the values I expect

Tags: c++, cuda, fft, cufft

I am currently debugging my code, where I use the CUDA FFT routines.

I have something like this (please see comments for my thoughts on what I do):

```
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>

void foo(double* real, double* imag, size_t size)
{
    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftDoubleComplex* inputData;
    cufftDoubleReal* outputReal;

    //Allocation of arrays:
    size_t allocSizeInput = sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex) * size;
    size_t allocSizeOutput = sizeof(cufftDoubleReal) * (size - 1) * 2;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&outputReal, allocSizeOutput);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&inputData, allocSizeInput);

    //Now I put the data in the arrays real and imag into input data by 
    //interleaving it
    cudaMemcpy2D(static_cast<void*>(inputData),
            2 * sizeof (double),
            static_cast<const void*>(real),
            sizeof(double),
            sizeof(double),
            size,
            cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaMemcpy2D(static_cast<void*>(inputData) + sizeof(double),
            2 * sizeof (double),
            static_cast<const void*>(imag),
            sizeof(double),
            sizeof(double),
            size,
            cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //I checked inputData at this point and it does indeed look like i expect it to.

    //Now I create the plan
    cufftPlan1d(&plan, size, CUFFT_Z2D, 1);

    //Now I execute the plan
    cufftExecZ2D(plan, inputData, outputReal);

    //Now I wait for device sync
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //Now I fetch up the data from device
    double* outDbl = new double[(size-1)*2]
    cudaMemcpy(static_cast<void*>(outDbl),
            static_cast<void*>(outputReal),
            allocSizeOutput,
            cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //Here I am doing other fancy stuff which is not important
}
```

So the problem I have now is, that the results in outDbl are not what I expect them to be. For example, if I give the following values into this function:

real = [0
-5.567702511594111
-5.595068807897317
-5.595068807897317
-5.567702511594111]

imag = [0
9.678604224870535
2.280007038673738
-2.280007038673738
-9.678604224870535]

I expect to get:

result = [-4.46511  -3.09563  -0.29805   2.51837   5.34042]

But i get something completely different.

What do I do wrong? Did I misunderstand the FFT function? Is it not basically the inverse FFT from complex to real? Is there a problem in my data copy routines?

I must admit I am a bit lost on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.. sorry. I found the answer on stackoverflow after I asked the question.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034609/not-the-same-image-after-cuda-fft-and-ifft?rq=1)

Basically: The cuda fft is not normalized so I have to divide the values I get by the number of elements to get the normalized values.